# Android - Uploading sqlite data and photos to a server

Tags: php, android, sqlite, file-upload

Hello I have several questions in mind.

I have an application that stores log data of the user as he or she logs in or out. After logging in or out, the user is prompted to take a photo and it is stored in a custom folder with a custom file name. Data regarding the time stamp, file name, room, file path, etc are stored in an SQLite database. I know it's stored properly because I'm able to view the results in a ListView properly.

The second step is uploading the said database to an online server (something like CPanel I guess) along with the photos. Here I got the impression that I need to export the SQLite database and upload it. The same goes for the photos in the said folder.

So here are my questions:

1. What is the best way of exporting an SQLite database keeping in mind that it will be uploaded to an online server? I know it is possible to export the SQLite as CSV, but is it possible to export the SQLite database as queries?
2. Is it possible to upload photos from a folder on the smartphone to another folder in the server?
3. Will I need to do some back end php scripting in order to to screw up the way the database and photos are uploaded into the server?

Thanks.

Comment: You can always just treat the sqlite database as the simple file it actually is, and upload that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the best way of exporting an SQLite database keeping in mind
>   that it will be uploaded to an online server?

Upload the data, not the database itself to your web server. This can be accomplished using a RESTful web service.

> I know it is possible to
>   export the SQLite as CSV, but is it possible to export the SQLite
>   database as queries?

Yes this is possible but you have to generate your own SQL queries since the `SQLite` dialect is different from the `MySQL` dialect.

> Is it possible to upload photos from a folder on the smartphone to
>   another folder in the server?

Yes it  is possible. Use a Web service / FTP Server / HTTP File Server

> Will I need to do some back end php scripting in order to to screw up
>   the way the database and photos are uploaded into the server?

Yes, you will need a web service to do the tasks for you.